# What kind of plant is this with a single, tall stem and alternate, carrot-like leaves?

Tags: identification, pots

I recently bought a house and have found this plant in a hanging basket in the back yard.  Can anyone identify it for me?
[image: hanging plant]
[image: close up of stem]
[image: close up of top]

Comment: It could also be certain species of Asteraceae. If you rub the leaves, is there any scent? Asteraceae often has a more chrysanthemum or yarrow-like scent, while Apiaceae species often heve a more carrot/parsley/fennel/dill type scent.

Comment: I think that I have a match... let me check some books but as @J.Musser say: it is from Asteraceae family. MethodsofSanity it smell like hell?

Comment: @J.Musser _Eupatorium capillifolium_ (Lam.) Small ex Porter & Britton but I never seen in real life.. just some illustrations. Searching pictures on Internet I can see a perfect match.. but you know.. Internet is wrong by default!

Comment: @ondoteam I crushed some of the stems coming from the base and I could not smell anything, but the pictures for Eupatorium capillifolium look very much like what I have growing in that pot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure because I never seen the plant other than illustrations and pictures... but I think that it is *Eupatorium capillifolium* (Lam.) Small ex Porter & Britton from the Asteraceae family.

I am not comfortable with technical English and I have only Spanish literature but you can read more about that plant in the links below.

[UMass E. capillifolium](https://extension.umass.edu/landscape/weeds/eupatorium-capillifolium)

[Botánica Y Jardines (Spanish)](http://www.botanicayjardines.com/eupatorium-capillifolium/)

Comment: I believe that it is Eupatorium capillifolium, the plant looks like pictures I have found online.  This would be a weed, correct?

Comment: @MethodsofSanity I don't believe in weeds (every plant is good for something), but yes, it is very invasive. If you don't like it, remove the plant (do not cut) from the root before floration. Have a nice day :)